# What is the value of $\frac{\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)}{\lim_{x\to 0^+}g(x)}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Let, $A=\mathbb R-\left\{0\right\}$ with

$$f:A\rightarrow\mathbb R,\quad g:A\rightarrow\mathbb R$$

$g(x)=\frac{2x}{|x|}$

$f(x)=\begin{cases}8-4x-g(-x),\,x≥0\\g(x)+x+6,\,x<0\end{cases}$

Then, what is the value of

$$\frac{\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)}{\lim_{x\to 0^+}g(x)}=?$$

**My attempt.**

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}g(x)=\frac{2x}{x}=2$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=8-\lim_{x\to 0^+}g(-x)=8-\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{-2x}{x}=8+2=10$$

So, $$\frac{\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)}{\lim_{x\to 0^+}g(x)}=5$$

My friend says me, my answer is correct, but my attempt is wrong.

She says  me

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\left(8-\color{red}{\frac{2x}{-x}}\right)=8+2=10$$

But, I can not understand my mistake.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your attempt.

Comment: The difference between the two attempts lies in $\dfrac{-2x}{x}$ versus $\dfrac{2x}{-x}$, which are basically the exact same things ; so both answers are equivalent (and correct) - and yours is better, since $\dfrac{-2x}{x}$ is more clearly equal to $g(-x)$ than the other one.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Yes, that is the problem. My friend says, I got the wrong result from absolute value.

Comment: For $x> 0$, $-x<0$ so |-x| = -(-x) = x. $g(-x)=\frac{2(-x)}{x}$. All is right.

Comment: @I'mastudent Well, don't (always) trust your friends.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you for your comment. As I said in other comments, I was afraid I wasn't evaluating $g(-x)$ correctly.

Comment: I think your friend is thinking that for $x < 0,$ we should write $\lvert x\rvert = -x,$ which is true ... for $x < 0.$ But in this case actually $x > 0$ and you have $\lvert -x\rvert = x.$

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong with your attempt. My guess is that your friend evaluated $\lim_{x\to 0^+} g(-x)$ differently. I can see two obvious ways to do it:

1. $\lim_{x\to 0^+} g(-x) = \lim_{x\to 0^+} \dfrac{2(-x)}{|-x|} = \lim_{x\to 0^+}\dfrac{-2x}{x} = -2,$
2. $\lim_{x\to 0^+} g(-x) = \lim_{t\to 0^-} g(t) = \lim_{t\to 0^-} \dfrac{2t}{|t|} = \lim_{t\to 0^-}\dfrac{2t}{-t} = -2.$

Since you calculated $\lim_{x\to 0^+} g(x)$ beforehand, you could also just notice that $g$ is an odd function, i.e. $g(-x) = -g(x)$. Then,

3. $\lim_{x\to 0^+} g(-x) = \lim_{x\to 0^+} (-g(x)) = - \lim_{x\to 0^+} g(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y = -x$

$8-\lim_{x\to 0^+}g(y)=8-\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{2y}{|y|}$

So$|y| = \left\{ \begin{matrix} x \ge 0 \Rightarrow x \\ x \le 0 \Rightarrow -x \end{matrix} \right.$

$x \to 0^+$ implies that $x > 0$ and $y = x$.

So $8-\lim_{x\to 0^+}g(y)=8-\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{-2x}{x}$